# SSH works through part of a script but not another

Tags: linux, ssh

We have a script that runs on server a and does alot of commands through ssh on server b.  for some reason this stoped working on one system.  I am not sure what to make of the ssh debug info getting dumped in my log.  It seems to do everything just fine except for the last part of the script.  Here is the ssh debug information.

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config^M
debug1: Applying options for *^M
debug1: Connecting to b-classicbeauty.cloudapp.net [137.117.44.178] port 22.^M
debug1: Connection established.^M
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2^M
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1^M
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3^M
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*^M
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0^M
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received^M
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none^M
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent^M
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent^M
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY^M
debug1: Host 'server b' is known and matches the RSA host key.^M
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2^M
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent^M
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent^M
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received^M
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password^M
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex^M
debug1: No valid Key exchange context^M
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic^M
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found
^M
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found
^M
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information

^M
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found
^M
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey^M
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity^M
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa^M
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277^M
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA^M
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).^M
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]^M
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com^M
debug1: Entering interactive session.^M
debug1: Sending environment.^M
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8^M
debug1: Sending command: cd /tmp/cloudbackup/95094; 7za a 95094081015.7z    cloudbackup -phuntforhonor^M
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0^M
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0^M
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1^M
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK^M
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK^M
debug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK^M
Transferred: sent 2584, received 2552 bytes, in 0.2 seconds^M
Bytes per second: sent 13219.8, received 13056.1^M
debug1: Exit status 2^M
```

So it sends all the data to the server through ssh.  then it successfully compresses said data, but the next command is to dumb that compressed data into a cloud storage and that is where it seems to clunk out.  i have confirmed that it not our jar file to accomplish that, that is causing this output.

Comment: Do the commands that are failing work OK if you run them by hand on the server you're connecting to? Do the all have exit status 0? You can check by running `echo $?` immediately after each command. I think one of the commands you're running is exiting with status 2 and ssh is just passing that back.

Comment: I will look into this.  What is odd is this all the sudden started happening without any changes to the script.